# Getting errors when adding progressbar and emptystate,check out my code

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm creating simple tour app with firebase which is almost finished but now i've added progressbar and emptystate both are not displaying. My app is getting crashed when there is not internet connection, i used if and else progress bar and empty state is not displaying

Check out my code and screenshot help me to solve this issue
[image]

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        Toolbar toolbar;
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        FirebaseAdapter mAdapter;
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataClass> options;
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(" Center");
       private  TextView mEmptyStateTextView;
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         //   View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
      mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if( activeNetwork != null &&
                    activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    
             
               mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
                toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
                this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    
                options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataClass>()
                        .setQuery(myRef, DataClass.class)
                        .build();
            }
            else {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyState);
                mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
           }
    
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerview);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mAdapter = new FirebaseAdapter(options, MainActivity.this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        }
    
    In Xml:
    
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_bg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/tool">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recylerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/emptyState"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    
            <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

Error:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bgcenter/com.example.bgcenter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bgcenter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
```

Comment: Try to change your variable declaration to `private ContentLoadingProgressBar mProgressBar` and your variable initialization to `mProgressBar = (ContentLoadingProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);`

Comment: Thanks bro for replying